# switch apk in google play that wrote on html5 with new adobe air apk

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I have an old game in Google play store that i was writing with html5.

I want to build the same game with as3 adobe air then When the user will update the app he will get new as3 game.

Is it possible?

Comment: of course take the same bundleID and update it and do not forget to invrement the version number in the manifest

Comment: thank you. do i need to use the old certificate key? because some how flash builder dont let me do it. i get "incorrect password for this certificate".

Comment: Yes you have to use the same key, and the error is quite clear, isn't it :)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wiki/HowTo

Comment: actually its not clear because this is the right password for the key:(

Comment: Maybe not, or your keystore file is corrupted

Comment: thank you for your time. when i use the key in eclipse with the old app it works perfect, but when i try to do it from flash builder with the new app i get this error.

Comment: Sorry never worked with the Adobe Flash builder perhaps you will find your answer elsewhere

Comment: Can you export a unsigned apk from the flashbuilder and sign it with command line

Comment: i wish. but i use native extension which i must pack within flash builder. the flash builder use *.p12 key and my original key has no .p12, do you think i should find away to convert the key?

Comment: hmmmmm maybe. Good luck